# HTML tag rendering

Tags: html

I have a simple insert program containing a RichTextEditor, which does nice formatting to the text and then stores it in the database.

When I store this in the database table it gets stored along with html tags.

But when I would want to do a select over the records from the same table, I get it in different format:

for example if from my richeditText, I had stored

```
<p>hello</p>
```

when I do a select I get it as

```
 &lt;p&gt;hello&lt;/p&gt;
```

how do I render this as html?

Comment: What language are you using to retrieve the information from your database?

Comment: What language did you use to store the information to your database?

Comment: Java via Hibernate query language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most serverside languages have builtin functions to do this kind of conversion,

with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

with Javascript: [Convert HTML Character Entities back to regular text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338963/convert-html-character-entities-back-to-regular-text-using-javascript)

MySQL: [is there a mysql function to decode html entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities)