# Remove html encoding for characters using Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

I would like to change the code view for my XML template from:

```
&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;
```

To:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

This is an example but it's the whole file that I need to be able to read..

Comment: What's the proper encoding language so I can read the XML file exported from MySql. I will need to edit it and re-import it. Please if you can advise, it's a huge file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use Notepad++ [HTML TAG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/) Plugin.

Check out [here](https://kollegaru.wordpress.com/tag/notepad/) for step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm running the plugin right now..still waiting for the end results. Just a last question sorry, do I need to re-encode before importing back the XML file to MySql? Any idea?

Comment: @user3001925 You probably need to do this as there is no function in mySQL to decode html. Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities).

Comment: Is it normal that it takes so long to decode? It's more than 15 mins now..and still running..

Comment: @user3001925 How large is your file?

Comment: It's a large file..something like 40.000 lines..

Comment: @user3001925 It seems not that strange since it's so large. Give it some time.