# Mysql umlauts and ampersands

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with umlauts and ampersands.

Basically in the database I have a varchar field with content

```
Umlauts &auml;&oslash;&auml;&auml;
```

Is it possible to select this field, but in the same query convert it to something more readable? 
It should be somehing like

```
SELECT  myfield as address 
from `table`
```

And it should show

```
  Address
  Umlauts ü ä
```

I was wondering if it's possible? Thank you very much hope this makes sense

Comment: Are you storing your data in a UTF8 column? Are you using the UTF8 charset for your web pages?

Comment: It's currently stored as latin1_swedish_ci , would storing as utf8_general_ci help? I'm not too sure about charset for the webpage because it's basically an API which calls my database directly

Comment: Try: utf8_unicode_ci. Also make sure that you are using a UTF8 header on the page that you are outputting your data.

Comment: I've tried what you have suggested however it didn't help.Thanks anyway

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities