# MYSQL storing special characters

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I have all my character sets to UTF-8 right now on my mysql database but for some reason when I use the Snipe IT application when putting a é or è or another special characters i get `&eacute;` in the database, any ideas on how to be able to change this?

Comment: Seems like your application is storing special characters as HTML entities. If you have no control over the storing part, you'll want to read and unescape the HTML entities on data retrievel - there's libraries for that in many languages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities