# How to load HTML character codes data correctly into My Sql database?

Tags: mysql, database

I receive a data file in ETL from the client and we load the data into Mysql database using Load Data file functionality and use CHARACTER SET 
 as utf8.

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${filePath}' 
      INTO TABLE test_staging
      CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
      (${testcolumns}) SET
      first_name = @first_name;
```

### Data from client

```
1|&quot;test&quot;|&quot;name&quot;|2
2|&quot;asdf&quot;|asdf&amp;test|2
3|fun|value|2
```

When I load the above data into the database and it is inserting directly as strings instead of converting to html characters

### Database Data

```
id   first_name       last_name
1   &quot;test&quot; &quot;name&quot;
2   &quot;asdf&quot; asdf&amp;test
3      fun                value
```

I tried changing the CHARACTER SET value from **utf8** to **latin1** but the result is same.

I also tried replacing the special characters while loading the data into database but the issue is, I receive all types of html characters data in the file. I cannot keep  on adding the replace function  for all of them.

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${filePath}' 
      INTO TABLE test_staging
      CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
      (${testcolumns}) SET
      first_name = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(first_name,'&apos;','\''),'&quot;','"'),'&amp;','&');
```

Is there any character set which converts the html data and loads correctly?

### Expected Database Data

```
id  first_name  last_name
1   "test"       "name"
2   "asdf"       asdf&test
3    fun        value
```

Any help is appreciated...  Thanks

Comment: This has been asked before a long time ago: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities), you could copy one the answers there. I didn't find any newer solutions. Something like PHP has [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), of course, but that's a real programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is not about character set. It happens because the software that your client use intentionally converts HTML special characters to their codes.

It is probably possible to convert them back using MySQL though I couldn't find a quick solution, but as you are handling this data with ETL the better option seems to be to use the external tool *before* you insert the data into the database. [One of these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5929492/6948900) for example:

- cat input-with-specialchars.html | recode html..ascii
- xmlstarlet unesc
- perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_);'

etc.

or something else depending on what tools you have available in your system or which ones you can afford to install.

Comment: I choose the option of resolving the data in shell script using xmlstarlet unesc. It resolved the special characters issue. The **recode** has not support for html5 versions so choose **xmlstarlet unesc**