# How to decode htmlencoded result in mysql command

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL query

[image]

Output

[image]

What I need to be as output

[image]

Need out put as below:

"l22s &apos;"   => "l22s ."

If there are any HTML encoded strings , I need to decode them in select.

Comment: is this useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678980/is-there-a-mysql-function-to-decode-html-entities

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to extend `WHEN POSITION(... IN locations.name) THEN REPLACE(locations.name, ..., ...)` statements as much as you need.

```
SELECT REPLACE(locations.name, '&apos;', '.')
FROM `locations`
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN POSITION("&apos;" IN locations.name) THEN REPLACE(locations.name, '&apos;', '.')
  WHEN POSITION(<yourSecondItem> IN locations.name) THEN REPLACE(locations.name, <yourSecondItem>, <yourSecondReplaceItem>)
END AS `Name`
FROM `locations`
WHERE <yourWhereCriteria>
```

Comment: If there are any HTML encoded strings , I need to decode them in select.

Comment: @kalanamw, have a look at updated answer.